# IDE with autocomplete feature for HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, macos, ide

I am looking for HTML and PHP editors (or IDE) that have auto-complete features. Please can anyone recommend?

1. IDE with auto-complete feature on Linux OS (Debian-based)
2. IDE with auto-complete feature on Mac OS (10.6)

Comment: note: I may be mis-applying the term IDE here. But what I want is an editor or an IDE that has an auto-complete feature. thanks.

Comment: How are you finding the PHP plugin for Eclipse? Does it have intellisense? Does it have templates for loops and other stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has an autocomplete function. On Mac you may have to do some extra configuration, but at my place it works like a charm!

You can find a download for eclipse PDT (PHP edition) [here](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/)

@Neilvert Noval
That is a yes :). Don't know how extensive you expect it to be.

Comment: Does eclipse PDT (PHP edition) can also do HTML autocompletion aside from PHP?

Comment: This will help. Thanks. I'll accept this answer since you are the first one to answer both my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

PHPStorm http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ offers the most adequate php class resolution and speed (which is important, as eclipse is terribly slow) and deployment features

Comment: it is a 30 day trial

Answer (score 3):

You can try Dreamweaver CS5. This is the IDE which I use and it totally serves my purpose. CS5 offers excellent PHP support.

Answer (score 2):

You may find answers from here:

For Linux web IDE:

http://www.codefear.com/linux/best-free-linux-web-programming-editors/

For Mac web IDE:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/macintoshhtmleditors/tp/free-macintosh-editors.htm

I recommend NetBeans or Eclipse

Comment: Actually I am using BlueFish in my *nix machine. And after looking at your links, I am surprised BlueFish supports Mac as well. I am currently downloading BlueFish as I typed this (for Mac). One point up for this help.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer netbeans for editing . It has an awesome autocomplete and can also show reference data for functions etc. using w3schools reference site. The IDE is very stable and one of my all time favourites.To view its home page [Click Here.](http://www.netbeans.org)

Also its debugging support for php is one of the best i have ever used.

Answer (score 1):

to answer number 1

you can try :

1. **eclipse**  : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr1

or the lite version of eclipse :
**easy eclipse** 
http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/index.html

1. **netbeans** : http://netbeans.org

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse (PDT) http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/. It's an PHP IDE and supports auto complete/hinting for JavaScript, HTML, PHP 5.3, CSS and more if you add more components for it. It runs on every system. I run it on ubuntu (debian based). MacOS will work.