# Eclipse automatic create new functions/methods

Tags: eclipse, methods, aptana

At work we're currently using an IDE called PHPEdit, however we're looking to move to another primary IDE, we've been looking at Aptana Studio 3 based off eclipse.

A very nice feature of PHPedit was you could create new methods by clicking a little tool tip under new methods.

For example you could type

```
$data = $this->model->getData();
```

and if the function getData() didn't exist you could click the word "getData" and get a little option to create the method, then it would automatically create it in the relevant model and if you passed any params through it like $var, $var, then it would auto set them up as well.

I was wondering if such feature is available or if anybody knows of one as I'm not overly sure what to be searching for in any documentation as I don't know what this is actually called.

Many thanks!

Comment: I know for sure that the Java IDE in eclipse provides this feature. Not sure about the php IDE though.

Comment: As far as I know, this feature does not exist in Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK eclipse PDT does not have exactly what you want.

You can have a look at [Linux programming editors](http://www.codefear.com/linux/best-free-linux-web-programming-editors/) and meybe even checkout [Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

While you are at it, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583061/ide-with-autocomplete-feature-for-html-and-php)

Comment: I don't suppose you know if it would be possible/simple to create an add-on/plugin/ruble thing that would allow you to do this?

Comment: If you are using eclipse and have a working knowledge of java, its not difficult to add a plugin which is invoked on auto-complete or the right click menu. Have a look at this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html for a basic tutorial to start at.

Comment: Ah well I'm actually using Aptana Studio 3, but was assuming they would share this feature, but I'll give that article a read thankyou.

Comment: @owen - could you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse already does that.
I just typed following code in my open editor.

```
Intent intent = new Intent()
// some code to init intent   
String data = getData(intent);
```

And of course it cried that getData() does not exist. When hovered with mouse, it gives options to create `getData(Intent)`. And when I choose to create this method, it gives following:

```
protected String getData(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well I officially hate you. I cannot get this to work, what language are you doing it in?

Comment: Well, since you hate me already, I am not gonna tell what language I am using :-)